# How use TP-LINK TL-WN8200ND v1.0 on ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, server, wireless, usb

*This question is heavily edited. At first I thought I only had issues with using the network manager but turns out my wifi USB adapter is not working properly with the existing driver. Therefore this question is updated for the purpose of finding a working driver.*

My USB wifi adapter is: TP-LINK TL-WN8200ND v1.0

Up to now I'm searching for a working driver for many hours.
It seems to be a common problem.

Many people claim that they got it working with installing this driver:

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/

But after installing this driver my adapter does not even show up on `sudo lshw -c network`.

Others suggested:

https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

It has some special changes for TL-WN8200ND but does not work for me (adapter still does not show up).

Another standard goto driver seems to be:

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

But the README specifically mentions the TL-WN8200ND not to be supported.
Installing this driver does work.

```
> sudo lshw -c network
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 19
    bus info: pci80000:00:19.0
    logical name: enp0s25
    serial: d0:50:99:c0:84:7c
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair resources: irq:25 memory:efd00000-efd1ffff memory:efd3c000-efd3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
*-network DISABLED
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci80000:02:00.0
    logical name: enp2s0
    version: 03
    serial: d0:50:99:c0:84:7d
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=3.16, 0x800004d6 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair resources: irq:18 memory:efc00000-efc7ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:efc80000-efc83fff
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    physical id: 1
    bus info: usb03:12
    logical name: wlx10feed2228ac
    serial: 10:fe:ed:22:28:ac
    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated

> nmcli device
DEVICE             TYPE        STATE            CONNECTION
wlx10feed2228ac    wifi        disconnected     --
```

It is also able to scan all wifi networks including mine:

```
> nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE    SSID      MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL   BARS    SECURITY
          Totoro    Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  100      ****    WPA2
```

But when I try to connect, it doesn't work:

```
> nmcli device wifi connect Totoro --ask
Password: <I'm entering my password here (tested with other devices)>
Error: Connection activation failed: (7) Secrets were required, but not provided.

> dmesg
.....
usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
rtl8192cu 3-12:1.0 wlx10feed2228ac: renamed from wlan0
.....
random: crng init done
random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
.....
new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx10feed2228ac: link is not ready
.....

> journalctl -xe
wpa_supplicant: wlx10feed2228ac: Authentication with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out
wpa_supplicant: wlx10feed2228ac: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=3 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant: wlx10feed2228ac: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Totoro" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
NetworkManager <warn> sup-iface [...,wlx10feed2228ac]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
NetworkManager <warn> device (wlx10feed2228ac): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
```

I did read that others have the same issue with this driver so I guess that that is the "unsupported" part.

Somewhere I did read the suggestion to install a custom driver someone rewrote:

https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

But the installation tells me that no wifi card is detected and then fails.

I'm out of ideas. I also feel like I tried so much (adding driver to blacklist, setting different boot options, editing different files, installing and removing drivers, changing power management, changing random mac generation) that I'm not sure what the state of the system is.

The pvaret driver nearly seems to work. The adapter is detected. Wifi scanning works. Just the connection somehow fails.
In the repo of this driver they suggest to try the "new" official driver but with everything I've done to the system I'm not sure on how to install the official driver again.

Additional information and files I changed or created (current state):

```
> dkms status
8192cu, 1.11, 4.15.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
8192cu, 4.0.2.9: added
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.15.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)


> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8006 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2357:0100
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


> sudo lshw -short
....
/0/100/14/0/c                      generic     802.11n WLAN Adapter
....
/1               wlx10feed2228ac   network     Wireless interface

> sudo lshw -c generic
*-usb:0
    description: Generic USB device
    product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
    vendor: Realtek
    physical id: c
    bus info: usb03:c
    version: 2.00
    serial: 0De04c000001
    capabilities: usb-2.00
    configuration: driver=rtl8192cu maxpower=500mA speed=400Mbit/s


> cat /etc/network/interfaces
allow-hotplug wlx10feed2228ac
auto wlx10feed2228ac

iface wlx10feed2228ac inet dhcp


> cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
network:
    ethernets:
        enq0s25:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2


> cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2


> cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown.keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no


> ls /etc/modprobe.d/
8192eu.conf    blacklist-ath_pci.conf    blacklist-firewire.conf
blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf    dkms.conf    iwlwifi.conf
rtl8192cu.conf    amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf    blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf    blacklist-rare-network.conf    intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
mdadm.conf    rtl8xxxu.conf


> cat /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0


> cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf
install rtl8192cu /bin/false
install rtl8192c_common /bin/false
install rtl8xxxu /bin/false


> cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf
blacklist rtl8192cu


> cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf
blacklist rtl8xxxu
```

---

Following the steps by @heynnema

### Step 1 (done, problem not solved):

- `/etc/network/interfaces` changed
- `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` configured
- `sudo netplan --debug generate` run without errors
- `sudo netplan apply` done
- `reboot` done

Testing for connection:

```
> ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable


> sudo netplan try
Job for netplan-wpa@wlx10feed2228ac.service canceled

An error occurred: Command '['systemctl', 'stop', 'systemd-networkd.service', 'netplan-wpa@*.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Reverting.
Warning: Stopping systemd-networkd.service, but it can still be activated by:
    systemd-networkd.socket
```

### Step 2 (ready to start)

```
> dkms status
8192cu, 1.11, 4.15.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
8192cu, 4.0.2.9: added
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.15.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

- `sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.11 --all` done
- `sudo dkms remove 8192cu/4.0.2.9 --all` done
- `sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all` done

Checking `dkms status` does not return anything

```
> dpkg -l wpa* | grep ii
ii  wpasupplicant 2:2.6-15ubuntu2.5 amd64     client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

- `sudo -H nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf` commented out
- `sudo -H nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf` commented out
- `sudo -H nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf` commented out
- `sudo -H nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf` commented out
- `reboot` done

Output for:

```
> sudo lshw -C network
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 19
    bus info: pci80000:00:19.0
    logical name: enp0s25
    version: 05
    serial: d0:50:99:c0:84:7c
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair resources: irq:26 memory:efd00000-efd1ffff memory:efd3c000-efd3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci80000:02:00.0
    logical name: enp2s0
    version: 03
    serial: d0:50:99:c0:84:7d
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=3.16, 0x800004d6 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair resources: irq:18 memory:efc00000-efc7ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:efc80000-efc83fff
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    physical id: 1
    bus info: usb03:12
    logical name: wlx10feed2228ac
    serial: 10:fe:ed:22:28:ac
    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.15.0-72-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Testing:

```
> ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 cdic fq_code1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:c0:84:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 3: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdic mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:c0:84:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 4: wlx10feed2228ac: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdic mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:fe:ed:22:28:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Scanning for wifi networks (worked and returns 19 networks - selection reduced to mine / "Totoro"):

```
> sudo iwlist wlx10feed2228ac scan | less
....
Cell 15 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          Channel: 6
          Frequency: 2.437 Ghz (Channel 6)
          Quality= 70/70 Signal level=37 dBm
          Encryption key:on
          ESSID:"Totoro"
          Bit Rates: 1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
          Bit Rates: 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 40 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
          Mode: Master
          Extra:tsf=...
          Extra: Last beacon: 16676ms ago
          IE: Unknown: ....
          ....
          IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
               Group Cipher : CCMP
               Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
               Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
....
```

Comment: Please try: `nmcli d wifi connect Totoro password my_password` that is, without the enclosing apostrophes. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 This does not work since the password has a '<' in it and that leads to other errors ('No such file or directory'). Is that a problem by itself? Is linux only able to handle certain characters in passwords? I have added some logs for more information.

Comment: Seems weird indeed. What do you get when you try `nmcli d wifi connect Totoro --ask`? (You will be prompted for the password.)

Comment: @Quasímodo I do get the password prompt. After entering the password I again get the `The Wi-Fi network could not be found` error.

Comment: What does: `sudo iwlist scan` tell us?

Comment: @chili555 a lot. I can't scroll within the terminal. I'm currently directly accessing the server and can't copy paste between machines. Are you looking for something specific? My wifi network does show up in the list.

Comment: I am hoping that you are using WPA2-CCMP and not TKIP. I am hoping you have a fixed channel, not auto select and I am hoping it is fixed either 2.4 gHz or 5 gHz, not auto select. Please try: `sudo iwlist scan | less` and use the arrow keys to go up and back. Get out of 'less' with Q.

Comment: I added the output at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Please try with the password in quotation marks: `nmcli device wifi rescan && nmcli device wifi list && nmcli device wifi connect Totoro password "1234567890" ` Does dmesg still report that the SSID is not found?

Comment: It seems this is a driver issue. I couldn't find a working driver... so not sure how to go forward. Maybe switch back to Windows Server.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I tried to summarize everything I tried with respect to the driver issue. I also added the output that you requested as well as everything I changed on the system.

Comment: @besnep thank you for the info. In your `sudo lshw -C network` output, I don't see an ethernet interface... maybe you didn't list all of the output? Is there any particular reason that you must use NetworkManager over Netplan? You've kind of mixed and matched the two. Is your server primarily connected via wireless or ethernet? Also, why did you make all of your mods in /etc/modprobe.d?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I have two ethernet interfaces. The server is only connected via wireless and therefore I didn't list them. The modprobe.d changes came from the various driver repositories. I did use NetworkManager since it seemed straight forward. I don't know what Netplan is. Does it do something more advanced that could help to solve this?

Comment: @besnep Go ahead and show me the full lshw output. I'll put together an answer that uses Netplan (which is what servers usually use). Ping me when the lshw is in your question.

Comment: @besnep also show me `lsusb`. Thanks. Before installing any custom drivers, and before you modified anything in /etc/modprobe.d, did any of the built-in drivers see the usb device?

Comment: @heynnema I have added all information (just keep in mind that I typed everything by hand, so there can be typos).

Comment: I don't know anymore if the wifi adapter was visible with the built-in drivers.

Comment: @besnep thanks for the extra hard work of hand typing it all! What I don't know if the built-in drivers, of which there are at least two that seem like they'll drive that adapter, and/or if the driver that you've got installed now really doesn't work, as per their documentation. Last item of info before I put together an answer... show me `dkms status`.

Comment: I added the `dkms status`.

Comment: @besnep Execute Step #1 in my partial answer. I don't necessarily expect it to work... but who knows... report back... then I'll write Step #2.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you've kind of got a bunch of conflicting drivers, and mods in /etc/modprobe.d. It'll take a while to sort it all out, and will probably take a few rewrites of this answer to get it all done. Game?

You were mixing NetworkManager and Netplan commands, but we'll switch over to using Netplan instead of NetworkManager, and temporarily use the driver that you have installed now.

## STEP #1

---

**First, edit** `/etc/network/interfaces`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

**Remove**...

```
allow-hotplug wlx10feed2228ac
auto wlx10feed2228ac

iface wlx10feed2228ac inet dhcp
```

**For now, add**...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

**Then edit** `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`

`ls -al /etc/netplan` # to get the .yaml filename

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/found_filename.yaml` # use the real filename here

**And change this**...

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enq0s25:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

**To this**...

Note: enter the proper password in the password field

Note: make sure spacing/indentation stays the same, and no tabs

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlx10feed2228ac:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "Totoro":
          password: "**********"
```

---

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # if there are no generate errors, apply the new config

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Note: I don't necessarily expect this to work... but who knows... Step #2 is around the corner.

## STEP #2

---

Now we need to remove the dkms drivers, and return to using the built-in drivers. There are actually at least two drivers that will run this wireless adapter, and we may have to blacklist one of them.

`dkms status` # view the current situation

`sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.11 --all`

`sudo dkms remove 8192cu/4.0.2.9 --all`

`sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all`

`dkms status` # should now return nothing

---

**Undo** the `/etc/modprobe.d` mods...

For the following files...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf`

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf`

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf`

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf`

Comment out their contents, but do not remove these files.

`reboot`

Then show me the current status of:

`sudo lshw -C network`

---

## STEP #3 (PENDING)

---

**Create this file**...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/dongle.conf`

**Add this content**...

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
# blacklist rtl8xxxu
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102705/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-use-tp-link-tl-wn8200nd-v1-0-on-ubuntu-serv).